# Declaring interceptors in a spring 4 application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have tried to declare interceptors in my spring application within my spring.xml configuration file. I am getting the error that:

```
Line 18 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 18; columnNumber: 16; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'interceptors'.
```

It also doesn't like my `annotation-driven` tag

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">
    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix">
            <value>/WEB-INF/jsp/</value>
        </property>
        <property name="suffix">
            <value>.jsp</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app" />
    <interceptors>
        <bean class="com.app.interceptors.LoginLogoutURLInterceptor" />
        <interceptor>
            <bean class="com.app.interceptors.AccountServletInterceptor" />
            <mapping path="/account/**" />
        </interceptor>
        <interceptor>
            <bean class="com.app.interceptors.AdminServletInterceptor" />
            <mapping path="/admin/**" />
        </interceptor>
        <interceptor>
            <bean class="com.app.interceptors.HomePageInterceptor" />
            <mapping path="/" />
        </interceptor>
        <interceptor>
            <bean class="com.app.interceptors.RegistrationServletInterceptor" />
            <mapping path="/register/**" />
        </interceptor>
    </interceptors>
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
</beans>
```

Am I declaring my interceptors in the correct configuration file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to declare the namespace for Spring MVC XML elements in the header of your XML file:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
```

And then use the `mvc` namespace for the `interceptors` element:

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <!-- ... -->
    </mvc:interceptor>
</mvc:interceptors>
```

See [17.16 Configuring Spring MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config) in the Spring reference documentation for more information.

Comment: thanks, I think I have more issues like that. Now it says that 'bean' is unexpected, One of '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc":mapping}' is expected.

Comment: Do you have an `mvc:mapping` element? Please carefully read [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-config-interceptors) to see what your configuration file should look like exactly.